Image with Clip-path Animated
I'm having issues trying to animate the clip-path while the image remains unmoved.


svg {
  transition: 2s;
  transform: matrix(3, 2, -2, 3, 0, 0);
}
<div>
  <svg version="1.1" id="careers_2" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 2880 1644" style="enable-background:new 0 0 2880 1644;" xml:space="preserve">
      <defs>
        <rect id="SVGID_1_" width="2854" height="1444"></rect>

      <clipPath id="rectMask">
        <use xlink:href="#SVGID_1_" style="overflow:visible;"></use>
      </clipPath>

      <clipPath id="Stage2" width="2328" height="956">
        <path class="Stage2Obj1" d="M5442.2-664.9L2214,173.6c-178.8,46.4-285.9,228.8-239.4,407.6l0,0c46.4,178.8,228.8,285.9,407.6,239.4 L5610.5-17.6L5442.2-664.9z"></path>

        <path class="Stage2Obj2" d="M-1506.4,1827.6l3228-839.5c178.8-46.4,285.9-228.8,239.4-407.6l0,0c-46.4-178.8-228.8-285.9-407.6-239.4 l-3228.1,839.3L-1506.4,1827.6z"></path>
      </clipPath>
      </defs>

      <g style="overflow:visible;clip-path:url(#rectMask);will-change: transform;">
        <image style="overflow:visible;" width="2880" height="1458" src="https://www.worldatlas.com/r/w1300/upload/fc/62/4f/shutterstock-1011270001.jpg" transform="matrix(0.9907 0 0 0.9907 0.3906 -2.497783e-02)" clip-path="url(#Stage2)">
        </image>
      </g>
    </svg>
  <div>



I'm trying to have the clip-path rotate while zooming in, which will reveal the image behind the mask. I've tried different styles, but I can't target the clip-path itself without having the same styles effect the image. I'm using a wiki image as an example.

So animate the path not the whole SVG?

Yes, animate the clip-path on top and not the image.

BTW:  svg's <image> element expects a href attribute not src. rotating the clipPath should work. See https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/JjVZNLj

@herrstrietzel I see it rotating fine, but I wanted it to rotate and blow out revealing all of the image behind it.
